# Core Data deadlocking when executing fetch requests inside performBlockAndWait blocks

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, deadlock

I am experiencing issues with Core Data which I cannot resolve. I've learned about concurrency issues in Core Data the hard way, thus I am really careful and only perform any core data operations in `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` blocks.

Here goes my code:

```
/// Executes a fetch request with given parameters in context's block.
+ (NSArray *)executeFetchRequestWithEntityName:(NSString *)entityName
                                 predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
                                fetchLimit:(NSUInteger)fetchLimit
                            sortDescriptor:(NSSortDescriptor *)sortDescriptor
                                 inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
    NSCAssert(entityName.length > 0,
          @"entityName parameter in executeFetchRequestWithEntityName:predicate:fetchLimit:sortDescriptor:inContext:\
          is invalid");

    __block NSArray * results = nil;

    NSPredicate * newPredicate = [CWFCoreDataUtilities currentUserPredicateInContext:context];
    if (predicate){
        newPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[newPredicate, predicate]];
    }

    [context performBlockAndWait:^{

        NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
        request.fetchLimit = fetchLimit;
        request.predicate = newPredicate;
        if (sortDescriptor) {
            request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
        }

        NSError * error = nil;
        results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (error){
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                           reason:@"Fetch requests are required to succeed."    
                                         userInfo:@{@"error":error}];
             NSLog(@"ERROR! %@", error);
        }

        NSCAssert(results != nil, @"Fetch requests must succeed");
    }];

    return results;
}
```

When I enter this method concurrently from two different threads and pass two different contexts, I result in a deadlock on this row: `results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];`

Which is interesting: it seems like both threads cannot acquire some lock on the Persistent Store Coordinator in order to execute a fetch request.

All of my contexts are `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

I can't put my finger on, why am I locking the app and what should I do differently. My research on Stack Overflow gave me nothing, since most of the people fixed all the locks by dispatching the fetch requests on the MOC's queue, which I already do.

I will appreciate any information on this issue. Feel free to provide documentation links and other long reads: I am eager to learn more about all kind of concurrency problems and strategies.

Comment: Could you provide code for: `currentUserPredicateInContext:` and `predicate` construction (do they use object from other contexts to get constructed)?

Comment: Are you sure it's a deadlock? I suggest you post the stack traces of the threads

Comment: @DanShelly The bug is very hard to reproduce, I didn't catch it today, so no stack traces. 
Predicates are of format "owner = %@", where %@ is a string from user defaults. I didn't use any MObjects in predicates at all.
I am sure it is a deadlock, since in the stack traces two of my threads are stuck on mutex_wait which results from a call to executeFetchRequest.

Comment: Any reason you are using a class method. That may be your problem.

Comment: We had this issue and we finally conceded defeat. We changed it to use `performBlock:` and used an asynchronous API (completion block).

Comment: My bet would be that the one of your contexts is a child of the other context you are calling the fetch from

Answer (score 2):

> Which is interesting: it seems like both threads cannot acquire some lock on the Persistent Store Coordinator in order to execute a fetch request.

The persistent store coordinator is a serial queue. If one context is accessing it another context will be blocked.

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator):

> Coordinators do the opposite of providing for concurrency—they serialize operations. If you want to use multiple threads for different write operations you use multiple coordinators. Note that if multiple threads work directly with a coordinator, they need to lock and unlock it explicitly.

If you need to perform multiple background fetch request concurrently you will need multiple persistent store coordinators.

Multiple coordinators will make your code only slightly more complex but should be avoided if possible. Do you really need to do multiple fetches at the same time? Could you do one larger fetch and then filter the in-memory results?

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in learning more about Core Data (and threading), the following website will be extremely helpful.   I attended Matthew Morey's talk at the Atlanta CocoaConf 2013.

High Performance Core Data (http://highperformancecoredata.com)

The companion sample code to the website is available at: https://github.com/mmorey/MDMHPCoreData

All you need to do in your app, is to have a Singleton instance (somewhere) of the MDMPersistenceStack class.

As far as your problem/issue, even though the Apple documentation for NSManagedObjectContext class, does allow for code to be written the way that you have (with the Core Data operations performed on an NSManagedObjectContext instance in a block) and to some extent encourages that - I would like to point out that is not the only way.

Whenever I have fixed apps that have Core Data concurrency issues (locking), the simplest thing, in my opinion, is to create a private NSManagedObjectContext inside the thread or block that I want to execute Core Data operations on.

It may not be the most elegant approach, but it's never failed me.   One is always guaranteed that the NSManagedObjectContext is created and executed in the same thread, because the NSManagedObjectContext is explicitly created.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
      /* 
         Create NSManagedObjectContext
         Concurrency of Managed Object Context should be set to NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
         If you use the MDMPersistenceStack class this is handled for you.
      */
      NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = ....  

      /*
         Call the method that you have listed in your code.  
         Let's assume that this class method is in MyClass
         Remove the block that you have in your method, as it's not needed 
      */
      [MyClass executeFetchRequestWithEntityName: ......]   // rest of parameters
});
```

Comment: That is a very poor answer. First of all, as stated in the [NSManagedObjectContext's class reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html)

Private queue (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) – The context creates and manages a private queue. (...) You use contexts using the queue-based concurrency types in conjunction with performBlock: and performBlockAndWait:. You group “standard” messages to send to the context within a block to pass to one of these methods.

Comment: Thus, what I am doing with those blocks is the right way to handle concurrency with contexts of NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType, and what you're suggesting is probably the way you do it with NSConfinementConcurrencyType contexts.

Comment: We're going to have to agree to disagree, that my answer is a poor answer. :-)  Maybe you don't like the part - where I tried to simplify things.  In a pre-iOS 4 world, this would have been an outstanding answer.

Comment: I'll update/edit the answer - to make the simple version use to use the MDMPersistenceStack class.   If you use the class, it will take care of the major issues/problems regarding threading and Core Data

Comment: What you are suggesting here is clearly against the documentation(see first comment). **NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType** means the context has _its_ _own_ _queue_, which you have to use for all context operations. You are telling me that I should use some random thread provided by dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) instead for context operations i.e. you are suggesting to ensure that operations are performed on **wrong** thread. If you'd tell me to use NSConfinementConcurrencyType context instead, your answer would be ok, but I need a synchronous call (see question).

Comment: I agree with @cpt.neverm1nd, you don't really answer the question, and creating a MOC with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` on its own thread is definitely an overkill.

Answer (score -1):

I did it this way. It fixed the issue for me. I was experiencing a lot of deadlocks too. See if it works for you.

```
    + (NSArray *)getRecordsForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{


@try
{
   __weak __block NSError *error = nil;

    __block __weak NSArray *results = nil;


    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        [context lock];

        results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        [context processPendingChanges];

        [context unlock];

    }];

    [self handleErrors:error];

    request = nil;
    context = nil;

    return results;
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    if([exception.description rangeOfString:@"Can only use -performBlockAndWait: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue"].location!=NSNotFound)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;

        [context lock];

       __weak NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        [context processPendingChanges];

        [context unlock];

        [self handleErrors:error];

        request = nil;
        context = nil;

        return results;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

}

Comment: One should never use exception handling in regular code in Objective-C. Exceptions are raised for logic, or internal errors only and should not happen in regular real-life situations. Specifically, you should make two methods here: one to fetch results for a context configured with a private queue, the other for other contexts.